# Spawning Multiple uWSGI Workers with Flask-SocketIO + gevent + uWSGI + nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-socketio

I have a Flask app running on Ubuntu with uWSGI, gevent and nginx, but I can't see from the [Flask-SocketIO docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) how to run multiple uWSGI workers. The docs suggest you have to run multiple uWSGI instances with a single worker(+thread), but I don't see how this is configured.

I have added 4 servers on different ports in the nginx config under socketio_nodes (as per the docs), and I start uwsgi once pointing to uwsgi.ini. How do I end up running 4 separate processes?

App snippet:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
.
.
.
if __name__=='__main__':
    from db import db
    db.init_app(app)
    socketio.run(app, host=config.HOST, port=config.PORT, debug=config.IS_DEBUG)
```

Config snippet:

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
gevent = 1000

http = :5000

strict = true          
master = true
enable-threads = true  
vacuum = true              
single-interpreter = true  
need-app = true                              
die-on-term = true                             
http-websockets = true

processes = 1
threads = 1
harakiri = 60                                 

wsgi-file = app.py
callable = app

logto = /var/www/html/project/log/%n.log
```

nginx config snippet:

```
upstream socketio_nodes {
        ip_hash;

        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
        server 127.0.0.1:5002;
        server 127.0.0.1:5003;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
        set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.1;
        real_ip_recursive on;

        root /var/www/html/project;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name [myurl] www.[myurl];

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;         
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";                
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://socketio_nodes/socket.io;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/html/project/static;
                expires 30d;
        }

.
.
.
```

Output:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.19.1 (64bit) on [Thu Sep 10 12:42:24 2020] ***
compiled with version: 7.5.0 on 17 June 2020 16:34:28
os: Linux-4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019
nodename: project
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /var/www/html/project
detected binary path: /var/www/html/project/venv2/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 15532
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
- async cores set to 1000 - fd table size: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :5000 fd 5
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:39459 (port auto-assigned) fd 4
Python version: 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27)  [GCC 8.4.0]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5641e7a01040
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 21036928 bytes (20543 KB) for 1000 cores
*** Operational MODE: async ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x5641e7a01040 pid: 31753 (default app)
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 31753)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 31785, cores: 1000)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 31786)
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x5641e7379a60] ***
```

Comment: You need to run each uWSGI separately, I don't think there is a way to do this from a single execution. You can create a different config file per instance with just a different port, or else use the same config but pass the port in the command line.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. Something is still wrong, I've started 3 uwsgi with separate config files (the only change is http=5000/5001/5002), and they are running fine. nginx config remains as above. All traffic seems to go to the first uwsgi server, the other 2 are silent. Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably okay. The ip_hash routing assigns a server based on the client's IP address. If your tests all come from the same IP then all requests are going to go to the same server.